# Change hyperlink color for one link in the footer

Tags: html, wordpress, css

When I inspect the link, I can see this:

```
#Bottom a {
color: #888;
}
```

I gave the link a class and added custom CSS but it's not working:

```
<a class="one" href="http://domain.com/contact.php">contact us</a>

#Bottom .one a:link {color:#0066D6; !important;}
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.one` class is being applied to the anchor, so there's no need to add `a:link` to the end of your selector, it would just be:

```
#Bottom a.one {
    color:#0066D6 !important;
}
```

Also, I would advise against using the `!important` declaration at all costs, especially in this case since it's not necessary. As long as the `.one` styling is added after the default link styling, it will override the styling without the need for the `!important` declaration(that's what Cascading, the 'C' in CSS, means).

**Example:**

```css
#Bottom a {
  color:red;
}
  #Bottom a.one {
    color:green;
  }
```

```html
<div id="Bottom">
  <a href="#">Standard Link</a>
  <a href="#">Standard Link</a>
  <a href="#">Standard Link</a>
  <a class="one" href="#">Special Link</a>
</div>
```